# Отобразить в админке Django отношения один-ко-многим

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть вопросы. Один вопрос может иметь несколько ответов. Есть модели *Question* и *Answer*.
Вот код:

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):

question_text = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Текст вопроса')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'вопрос'
    verbose_name_plural = 'вопросы'

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text


class Answer(models.Model):

question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Текст ответа')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'ответ'
    verbose_name_plural = 'ответы'

def __str__(self):
    return self.answer_text
```

Проблема вот в чем. Я вижу в админке какое-то неправильное отображение этих отношений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, я к ответу могу добавлять вопросы. А надо наоборот! Коллеги, подскажите, как решить проблему?

UPDATE

Я попытался использовать это [inlineModels](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

Но это тоже не дало результата. Вот код из *admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question
from .models import Answer


admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Answer)


class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AnswerInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Читать про [инлайны](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

Comment: Спасибо. Только не могу понять по документации. Мне отдельный файл сделать или где эти классы объявить?

Comment: Классы инлайнов объявляются обычно в admin.py вместе с обычными админскими классами.

Comment: Отлично! Я попробую прямо сейчас. Вы могли бы оформить этот комментарий, как ответ.

Comment: Это не помогло. Я добавил код,  как в документации и никакого эффекта в админке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Answer, Question


class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer


@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AnswerInline,
    ]
```